# What's the difference between equality (=) and inequality (<>) on BIT field in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, datatypes

Is there difference between `WHERE [BitField] = 1` and `WHERE [BitField] <> 0`?

They seem *logically* equivalent.

SQL Server, however, disagrees and creates slightly different execution plans. (Which is bad because the second form doesn't use existing indexes very effectively.)

Am I missing something, or it is just the way inequality operators behave?

Comment: My first thought was that an inequality operator isn't [sargable](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2016/09/13/what-is-a-sargable-predicate/). But inequality seems to be sargable. But maybe not in all cases? If nothing else, maybe this observation will give someone else an idea.

Comment: There is some discussion here about the sargability of bit operations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270461/any-disadvantages-to-bit-flags-in-database-columns

Comment: What happens if you put a redundant check constraint on the bit column enforcing that it has to be `IN (0,1)`? Will the optimiser then convert it to the equality version?

Comment: @Martin Smith: "_Will the optimiser then convert it to the equality version?_" It will. That's pretty neat trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> They seem logically equivalent.

They are.  Even with [ANSI_NULLS OFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) "a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> XYZ_value returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not NULL."

I found an old feedback item for this [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32908432-convert-inequality-predicates-on-bit-boolean-col), you can go vote for it.